# Finding Perfect numbers; control structures in java

Tags: java, controls, counter

Hey guys i'm trying to write a code for finding the first 4 natural numbers, but I can't find why my code fails to get me an anwer. I get nothing as an output and the program ends without giving me an output. Please, do tell me what exactly is wrong with my logic. Thank you!

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        int sum = 0, check = 1, min = 1;
        while(min < 10000){
            while(check<min){
                if(min % check == 0){
                    sum = sum + check;
                }
                check++;
            }
            if(sum == min){
                System.out.println(sum);
            }
            min++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Natural numbers are integers greater than 0, e.g. 1,2,3,4,5. Did you mean primes?

Comment: The title says you are looking for "perfect numbers" (natural numbers that are the sum of their positive divisors) is this true?

Answer (score 1):

Your mean is find the first four perfect numbers?

```
int i = 0; // or i = 1
int count = 0;
while (count < 4) {
    int k = 0;
    for (int j = 1; j < i; j++) {
        if (i % j == 0) {
            k += j;
        }
    }
    if (k == i) {
        count++;
        System.out.println(k);
    }
    i++;
}
```

Output

```
0
6
28
496
```

or if start `i = 1`

```
6
28
496
8128
```

Comment: Thanks for the response my man. But is it possible to find these numbers without really setting up a count to find just four let’s say if I had to find all the perfect integers between 0 and 100000. How would I approach that and where exactly does my logic fails, in the above example, that I get a wrong result? Thank you

Comment: Instead of `count < 4` you'd have `count < 100000` as the condition for your while loop.

Comment: Initial value of `i` is arbitrary as long as 0 <= i < 6